# Проверка пунктуации в тексте

Tags: пунктуация, корректура, текст

Будете кормить насильно?
- Нет, но…. Вы не облегчаете жизнь, ни себе, ни нам.
- Я не звала вас в свою жизнь, - довольно резко ответила я. – Как долго будут идти разбирательства?
- Они уже закончены. Леди Акаша хочет увидеть вас после обеда, а уже потом вынести решение. 
- Решение, - повторила я, как эхо. – Она его уже давно приняла, только будет играть со мной, как кошка с мышкой. Это, как раз, в её духе. Можете не отвечать, - я отошла к окну. – Я не буду есть. Если Ильче казнят, в моей жизни смысла больше не останется. Так стоит ли её поддерживать?
Девушка промолчала и, не дождавшись от меня больше ни слова, тихо вышла, оставив накрытый стол. Я равнодушно отвернулась от еды, усевшись на широкий подоконник. Решётки на окнах предохраняли меня от падения вниз. И, видимо, от побега. Я раздумывала над всем, что произошло за последние недели. И мысли мои были безрадостными. Жила-была себе я, и всё было сравнительно хорошо, не хватало только детей в моей счастливой картине мира. И вот, появились шалы и несчастной жизнь стала сразу у большого количества людей. Не слишком ли много вины на одни мои не очень мощные плечи?!
- Рада, леди Акаша ждёт вас, - Арм стоял у дверей. Его взгляд упал на нетронутый обед, он чуть нахмурился, но ничего не сказал. Уже хорошо, потому что я из последних сил держалась, чтобы не впасть в истерику. Честно говоря, её задержало послание Мили.

Comment: Что-то тире непутёвое: сжимается и тянется в пределах строки произвольно. Вы проверяли текст перед тем, как озадачить других?

Comment: Какое тире?)) Я, собственно, скинула в надежде получить ответ сразу, типа онлайн)) Но спасибо и за теперешний. Учту все замечания!. Хотя..текст не мой, меня саму просили проверить на ошибки.

Answer (score 1):

Ну, если по-быстрому, без особых "разборов", то я вижу так.

— Будете кормить насильно?
— Нет, но…[Четвертая точка лишняя.] Вы не облегчаете жизнь [без запятой] ни себе, ни нам.
— Я не звала вас в свою жизнь, — довольно резко ответила я. — Как долго будут идти разбирательства?
— Они уже закончены. Леди Акаша хочет увидеть вас после обеда, а уже потом вынести  решение. [Я бы написала так: Леди Акаша хочет видеть вас после обеда и уже потом вынесет решение.]
— Решение, — повторила я, как эхо. — Она его уже давно приняла, только будет играть со мной, как кошка с мышкой. Это как раз в её духе. [Как раз — без обособления.] Можете не отвечать. [точка] — Я [с заглавной]  отошла к окну. — Я не буду есть. Если Ильче казнят, в моей жизни смысла больше не останется. Так стоит ли её поддерживать? [абзац]

Девушка промолчала и, не дождавшись от меня больше ни слова, тихо вышла, оставив накрытый стол. Я равнодушно отвернулась от еды, усевшись на широкий подоконник. [с новой строки]
Решётки на окнах предохраняли меня от падения вниз. И, видимо, от побега. Я раздумывала над всем, что произошло за последние недели. И мысли мои были безрадостными. Жила-была себе я, и всё было сравнительно хорошо, не хватало только детей в моей счастливой картине мира. И вот [без запятой] появились шалы(**?**), [запятая] и несчастной жизнь стала сразу у большого количества людей. Не слишком ли много вины на одни мои не очень мощные плечи?! [абзац]

— Рада, леди Акаша ждёт вас.[точка] — Арм стоял у дверей. Его взгляд упал на нетронутый обед, он чуть нахмурился, но ничего не сказал. [с новой строки]
Уже хорошо, потому что я из последних сил держалась, чтобы не впасть в истерику. Честно говоря, её задержало послание Мили.

Какая-то смысловая рассогласованность, оторванность образовалась в самом конце.
Задержать (или сдержать) можно начало истерики. Если истерический процесс уже пошел, то его возможно только попытаться прекратить (чем-то резким или неожиданным).

[**как раз**](https://phraseology.academic.ru/5139/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA_%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7)
3. Именно, точно.

Comment: *Вы не облегчаете жизнь, ни себе...* — здесь, я думаю, не нужна запятая. И "новая строка" это всегда "абзац", других ведь не бывает.

Comment: Забыла! ТАМ я хотела добавить **никому**. Под абзацем я подразумеваю не только переход на новую строку, но и ее пропуск - для визуального разделения. Спасибо за подсказку и оценку. Добавлять?

Comment: Я бы просто убрал запятую, но спорить не буду. Если это для книги, какой может быть пропуск строки? :)

Comment: Я имела в виду что-то подобное (в современной печати очень часто встречается). https://www.litres.ru/elena-zvezdnaya/shepot-v-temnote/chitat-onlayn/page-2/

Comment: Спасибо, всё учту!